# Streaming real-time data from Jawbone

Tags: jawbone

Is there any way to see in one compact view details about the signals, taken from the Jawbone UP wristband in real-time? I am personally interested in detecting light, REM and deep sleep and have access in real-time while someone is sleeping.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If i am not mistaken, [this](https://jawbone.com/up/developer) is official page for developers that describes API for all Jawbone products. Check SDK for iOS/Android(depending on which platform u are developing), [here](https://github.com/Jawbone/UPPlatform_Android_SDK) is example of Jawbone SDK for Android, and it looks good documented

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not possible to get real-time sleep depth values from UP. These values are not calculated until the user wakes up and then the entire sleep is evaluated.

This may change in the future.